# How to check if file exists and echo it?

Tags: jquery, html

The function currently works only when an address is entered and the button is pressed.

I want to remove the button and remove the input, and when i loading the page it will take the address from var and check + echo the result

How to do it please?

```
http://jsfiddle.net/3uua075z/
```

---

```
<input type="text" id="name">
<button type="submit" id="button" value="Submit">Check</button>
<input type="text" id="answer">
// the new var that i want, Instead of the input
var url = "http://website.com/1.mp4";


function checkIfRemoteFileExists(){
    var answerBox = document.getElementById('answer');
    $.ajax({
        url:document.getElementById('name').value,
        error: function()
        {
            answerBox.value = "0";
        },
        success: function()
        {
            answerBox.value = "1";
        }
    });
}
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", checkIfRemoteFileExists);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your JavaScript in a `script` tag next to the `script` tag that loads jQuery and replace `document.getElementById("name").value` with the URL you stored in the variable. Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var checkUrl = "http://website.com/file.txt";


  function checkIfRemoteFileExists() {
    var answerBox = document.getElementById('answer');
    $.ajax({
      url: checkUrl,
      error: function () {
        answerBox.value = "0";
      },
      success: function () {
        answerBox.value = "1";
      }
    });
  }

  // invoke the method right away
  checkIfRemoteFileExists();
});
```

Also, if you just want to check if the files exist on the server or not and don't care about the content/body, you might wanna make a HEAD request instead of GET. It's a bit faster this way.

Comment: Thank you, i did it ok? https://jsfiddle.net/jkbdjwt8/1/ Because the code does not work for some reason

Comment: You can now remove the first two lines in the HTML to get rid of the input field and the check button. Btw, the file you're referring to in the url is not accessible. Try loading it in the browser first.

Comment: yes i did, but the problem its not show that the code working. no 1 or 0. https://jsfiddle.net/jkbdjwt8/5/ something not good there?

Comment: If your question is why isn't it printing 0 in the answerBox in the fiddle,  it is because jQuery is not loaded for your document. In the JavaScript section, click the dropdown titled `JavaScript + No-Library (pure JS) `, go to `FRAMEWORKS & EXTENSIONS` and select `jQuery (edge)` Then try running your example.